# Two screens overlapping while navigating using navigation component , only is some specific os

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

Bug comes in versions : Android version 9, oxygenos 9.0.6 , MIUI All versions of mi phone

Is it specific to os issue or navigation component in api level 26 ,

has anyone found two screens overlap while navigating? , if yes please suggest workaround for the issue

Answer (score 0):

I have given too much time tracing the issue , and finally got the solution

```
    android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
```

when I don't specify this attribute it will causing the issue in some os versions

Comment: I think it's basically the same issue as fragments overlapping to each other.